# how can i reference the namespace in values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to be able to reference the current namespace in `values.yaml` to use it to suffix some values like this

```
# in values.yaml
someParam: someval-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

It much nicer to define it this way instead of going into all my templates and adding `{{ .Release.Namespace }}`. If I can do it in `values.yaml` it's much clearer and only needs to be defined in one place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [named templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#named-templates) to define re-usable helper templates.  E.g.

In `templates/_helpers.tpl`:

```
{{- define "myChart.someParam" -}}someval-{{ .Release.Namespace }}{{- end -}}
```

In `templates/configmap.yaml` (for example):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: something
data:
  foo: {{ template "myChart.someParam" . }}
```

The result:

```
$ helm template . --namespace=bar
---
# Source: helm/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: something
data:
  foo: someval-bar
```

Comment: this is what i would like to avoid. having to update all my templates to use `.Release.Namespace`. that also means the chart is doing some magic that isnt as clear. I want to pass the full value in from values.yaml so its visible in the config what the value is- instead of it getting dynamically created in ALL of my templates

Comment: “Values files are plain YAML files” [[source](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#values-files)]. So I believe you can’t have any sort of templating or interpolation in your `values.yaml`.

Comment: With my solution, you will not need to update all templates to have `{{ .Release.Namespace }}`. But yes, in my solution the chart is doing “some magic” and it won’t be visible without seeing the rendered templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `someParam` might contain templating constructs, Helm includes a [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#using-the-tpl-function) function that interprets it.

```
- name: SOME_VARIABLE
  value: {{ .Values.someParam | tpl }}
```

If a chart allows this it generally documents it.  As a specific example, the [helm/charts PostgreSQL chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql) documents that its `configurationConfigMap` setting is

> ConfigMap with the PostgreSQL configuration files (Note: Overrides `postgresqlConfiguration` and `pgHbaConfiguration`). **The value is evaluated as a template.**

So for that specific value, you can put a template macro in the `values.yaml` file.

Comment: Im writing my own chart. is `tpl` just available in values.yaml? or do you have to do something to have that work. values.yaml isnt a template so how is tpl accessible in it?

Comment: `tpl` is a Helm-specific extension to the Go `text/template` language.  The code sample is intended to be a sample environment variable you might put in a deployment spec.  If `someParam` contains the string you show in the question, `tpl` will re-evaluate it.

Comment: so will this get the namespace if I do `someParam: someval-{{ .Release.Namespace | tpl }}`

Comment: If something runs `tpl` on `.Values.someParam`, then that construct will cause any macros in the target namespace to be expanded; given that `{}` aren't allowed in namespace names, `tpl` there won't do anything.

Comment: hmm then how does this answer my question? maybe im being dumb here, not sure how to use it to get namespace

Comment: Where your chart _uses_ `.Values.someParam`, call `tpl` on it, and the namespace will be expanded.

Comment: you mean where it uses it in all of my templates? how is that different then just using `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` in my templates?

Comment: When I deploy it, I can `helm install --set someParam='{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Release.Name }}-someval'` if I don't want to include the namespace and prefer a different convention.  (But yes, you need the `tpl` call on every use or in a shared helper to cause the expansion to happen.)

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify:

As described by community: [Amit Kumar Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57641009/11207414) and [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57641142/11207414) there is no good solution natively supported by [helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/) in order to change this behavior without modifying templates.
It looks that in your case (without modifying helm templates) the best solution it will be just using **set** with parameters during helm install.

like:

```
helm install --set foo=bar --set foo=newbar ./redis
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal in github for what you're asking: [Proposal: Allow templating in values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2492)

From one of the latest comments:

> This is the first thread I ran into, than also comment here...
>   See also [#2514](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2514)
>
> :) Thankfully, latest Helm manual says how to achieve this.
>   https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function
>
> The trick is enclosing variable in `"` or in a yaml block `|-`, and than
>   referencing it in a template as `{{ tpl .Values.variable . }}` This
>   seems to make Helm happy.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $ cat Chart.yaml | grep appVersion appVersion: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-d2e2f42
>
>
> $ cat platform/shared/t/values.yaml | grep -A2 image: image:    tag:
> |-
>     {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
>
>
> $ cat templates/deployment.yaml | grep image:
>           image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ tpl .Values.image.tag . }}"
>
>
> $ helm template . --values platform/shared/t/values.betradar.yaml |
> grep image
>           image: "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/namespace/service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-d2e2f42"
>           imagePullPolicy: Always
>       image: busybox
> ```
>
> Otherwise there is an error thrown..
>
> ```
> $ cat platform/shared/t/values.yaml | grep -A1 image: image:    tag:
> {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
>
> 1 $ helm template . --values platform/shared/t/values.yaml | grep
> image Error: failed to parse platform/shared/t/values.yaml: error
> converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface
> {}]interface {}{".Chart.AppVersion":interface {}(nil)}
> ```