# Kubernetes - Set Release.Namespace to dependencies values on values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, kong

I know there are many questions around this but I didn't find any with a real answer.

My helm chart have dependencies from another helm charts and I need to override their values with my `.Release.Name` and `.Release.Namespace`.

**My requeriments.yaml**

```
dependencies:
- name: keycloak
  alias: keycloak-config
  repository: https://my-repository.com/
  version: 1.0.0
- name: kong
  alias: kong-config
  repository: https://my-repository.com/
  version: 1.0.0
```

**On my values.yaml**

```
kong-config:
  websso:
    service:
      fullnameOverride: "my-helm._RELEASE_NAMESPACE_.svc.cluster.local"
      ckngOauth2Opts: "--data config.post_logout_redirect_uri=/_RELEASE_NAME_
                       --data config.logout_path=/_RELEASE_NAME_/logout"
```

I basically need to use `{{ .Release.Name }}` where I have `_RELEASE_NAME_` and `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` where I have `_RELEASE_NAMESPACE_`.

I already tried:

- `{{ .Release.Name }}` and `{{ .Release.Namespace }}`
- `$RELEASE_NAME` and `$RELEASE_NAMESPACE`
- `${RELEASE_NAME}` and `${RELEASE_NAMESPACE}`

but nothing works.

Note I really need to access those values at `values.yaml`. I don't have access to my dependencies code to change and set that values on that.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can only use variable references (or other templating syntax) in the `values.yaml` file if the chart author specifically allows for it.  If you don't have any control over the charts you're including, then this isn't possible.

Comment: [how can i reference the namespace in values.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633472/how-can-i-reference-the-namespace-in-values-yaml) is conceptually very similar.

Comment: I think this should be a feature in helm, we should probably get them to add it. Ideally you'd be able to just put a `namespace` field right on the dependency object and it would set that to `.Release.Namespace` and use the `name` field of the dependency for `.Release.Name`. 

The only other option is to make a change to the dependency to reference a nameespace and name from values rather than the .Release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this executing one additional command outside of my helm chart. As I have a `Makefile` file for my project build process where I can run some scripts for the multiple stages of my build. And so I added this command to the deploy stage:

```
sed -i "s/_RELEASE_NAMESPACE_/$(NAMESPACE)/g" $(MODULE_PATH)/chart/values.yaml
```

This works for a build workflow in some tool. But when I want to install manually my helm chart somewhere, it can't be done and I need to change manually that value with the server value.

Answer (score 3):

While it does not appear that helm, itself, can do that, [helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile#readme) can via either its [integration with kustomize](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile#helmfile--kustomize) or with its [`prepare` hook](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile#hooks). I'll show the `prepare` hook because it's much shorter

```yaml
releases:
- name: kong-config
  chart: whatever/kong
  version: 1.0.0
  values:
  - ./generated-values.yaml
  hooks:
  - events: ['prepare']
    command: bash
    args:
    - -c
    - |
      printf 'websso:\n  service:\n    fullnameOverride: my-helm.{{`{{ .Release.Namespace }}`}}.svc.cluster.local\n' > generated-values.yaml
```